# Array management in php

Tags: php, magento

Its generally related to a question in magento ..but i think using core php can also give me a wat i want

Im having a looping array issue here,My aray is like this

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 2
                [parent_id] => 1
                [name] => Koffersenkisten
                [is_active] => 0
                [position] => 1
                [level] => 1
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [category_id] => 40
                                [parent_id] => 2
                                [name] => Muziek
                                [is_active] => 1
                                [position] => 1
                                [level] => 2
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [category_id] => 46
                                                [parent_id] => 40
                                                [name] => Gitaar koffer
                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                [position] => 1
                                                [level] => 3
                                                [children] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [category_id] => 50
                                                                [parent_id] => 46
                                                                [name] => Bas gitaar koffer
                                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                                [position] => 1
                                                                [level] => 4
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [category_id] => 51
                                                                [parent_id] => 46
                                                                [name] => Electrische gitaar koffer
                                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                                [position] => 2
                                                                [level] => 4
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [2] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [category_id] => 47
                                                                [parent_id] => 46
                                                                [name] => Akoestische gitaar koffer
                                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                                [position] => 3
                                                                [level] => 4
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [3] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [category_id] => 49
                                                                [parent_id] => 46
                                                                [name] => Gitaar soft cases
                                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                                [position] => 4
                                                                [level] => 4
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [4] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [category_id] => 52
                                                                [parent_id] => 46
                                                                [name] => Gitaar gig bags
                                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                                [position] => 5
                                                                [level] => 4
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [5] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [category_id] => 53
                                                                [parent_id] => 46
                                                                [name] => Pedalboards
                                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                                [position] => 6
                                                                [level] => 4
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [6] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [category_id] => 48
                                                                [parent_id] => 46
                                                                [name] => Amp Utility Vehicles
                                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                                [position] => 7
                                                                [level] => 4
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [category_id] => 67
                                                [parent_id] => 40
                                                [name] => Percussie koffer
                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                [position] => 2
                                                [level] => 3
                                                [children] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [category_id] => 73
                                                                [parent_id] => 67
                                                                [name] => Tom koffer
                                                                [is_active] => 1
                                                                [position] => 1
                                                                [level] => 4
                                                                [children] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                    )

                                                            )

.......


......


>> it goes like this based on the number of categories
```

How do i get a simple array of the above like this

```
array('2' => 'Koffersenkisten','40'=> 'Muziek'...........etc); where 2 is the category_id and Koffersenkisten is the name
```

Comment: Please expand your desired result. Show 4-5 entries in it. For example for category_id 51 it's not clear to me what should be done, flatten that one out too?

Comment: If you want to flatten the array - it was already asked on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538906/convert-a-nested-array-into-a-flat-array-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function iterates over all items, and recurses when children are found. It passes the output array along at every invocation and appends to it:

```
function get_cats(array &$output, array $arr)
{
        foreach ($arr as $item) {
                $output[$item['category_id']] = $item['name'];
                if (count($item['children'])) {
                        get_cats($output, $item['children']);
                }
        }
}

// start with empty result
$output = array();
get_cats($output, $a);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: perfect and thanks !! although i modded your function a little bit to my needs

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Didn't test it.

```
   $result = array();

   function buildArray($array, $stack)
   {
      foreach($array as $item)
      {
         $stack[$item['category_id']] = $item['name'];

         if(isset($item['children']) && count($item['children']) > 0)
           foreach($item['children'] as $child)
              buildArray($item['children'], &$stack);
      }
   }

   buildArray($array, &$result);

   print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution (the array should be in `$list` before, the created array will be in `$result` after calling the *create* function):

```
function create($list, &$result) {
    if (is_array($list) && !isset($list['category_id'])) {
        foreach ($list as $element) {
            create($element, $result);
        }
    } else {
        $result[$list['category_id']] = $list['name'];
        create($list['children'], $result);
    }
}

create($list, $result);
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/KdKox).